# SQL subqueries calculations

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, oracle-apex

I have this table:

```
╔═════╤═══════╤═══════╗
║ ID  │ Group │ Value ║
╠═════╪═══════╪═══════╣
║ ID1 │ 1     │ 10    ║
╟─────┼───────┼───────╢
║ ID2 │ 1     │ 5     ║
╟─────┼───────┼───────╢
║ ID2 │ 1     │ 4     ║
╟─────┼───────┼───────╢
║ ID2 │ 1     │ 6     ║
╟─────┼───────┼───────╢
║ ID1 │ 2     │ 1     ║
╟─────┼───────┼───────╢
║ ID2 │ 2     │ 7     ║
╟─────┼───────┼───────╢
║ ID2 │ 2     │ 8     ║
╟─────┼───────┼───────╢
║ ID2 │ 2     │ 3     ║
╟─────┼───────┼───────╢
║ ID3 │ 3     │ 6     ║
╟─────┼───────┼───────╢
║ ID2 │ 3     │ 4     ║
╟─────┼───────┼───────╢
║ ID2 │ 3     │ 1     ║
╟─────┼───────┼───────╢
║ ID2 │ 3     │ 9     ║
╚═════╧═══════╧═══════╝
```

I want to do the following:

1. Find all Groups where ID = ID1
2. Extract the average values of ID2 belonging to the same group as ID = ID1

ID1 is only found in Group1 and Group2. Therefore the average of ID2 in
Group1 = (5+4+6)/3 = 5

and Group2 =  (7+8+3)/3 = 6

3. Calculate the percent of the value of ID1 relative to the average of ID2 for each group.

Group1 = (10*100%)/5 = 200%

Group2 = (1*100%)/6 = 16%

I know how to do the steps separately but I don't know how I can use the list of the first queries (the groups) in the second query.

Search_Item = 'ID1'

```
Select Group FROM MyTable WHERE ID = 'ID1'
```

-> Return 1 and 2

```
Select AVG(Value) FROM MyTable WHERE ID = 'ID2' AND Group = '1' 
Select AVG(Value) FROM MyTable WHERE ID = 'ID2' AND Group = '2'
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results in a readable format.

Comment: which rdbms are you using (oracle MySQL sql server?)

Comment: I am using Oracle/Apex5. How can I provide sample data?

Comment: @snowflake Can you provide your expected or desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT t.group,NVL(avg(s.value),0),(MAX(t.value)*100/NVL(avg(s.value),1)) as Perc
FROM(
    SELECT group,max(value) as value FROM MyTable WHERE ID = 'ID1' group by group) t
LEFT OUTER JOIN Mytable s
 ON(t.group = s.group and s.ID = 'ID2')
GROUP BY t.group
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I am trying to digest it...Your code gives my the average of the ID2 values. How can I use that result to divide by the single value of ID1?

Comment: Thank you very much @sagi, it helped a lot. May I ask one more question, I am not sure why I need Left outer join, could you help me to understand this part? I am new to SQL, the rest I understood.

Comment: (MAX(t.value) should be (MAX(s.value), right? Could you please correct it? Thanks

Comment: The sub-query `t` does not expose a `value` column so `MAX(t.value)` will throw an exception.

Comment: @snowflake It can't be `MAX(s.value)` as the `s` table is filtered to only query those rows where the `ID` is `ID2`.

Comment: @snowflake It was a typo becuase you asked me to add something else to the query.. forgot to add it to the inner query. It is corrected now and will work

Comment: Ok many thanks for the correction, it works now. Unfortunately I can not accept two answer, I don't how this is handled (First come first served?)

Comment: Usually, but choose which one you want @snowflake

Comment: I liked both solutions a lot because I learned many different things, also the task was the same. I would like to accept sagi's solution because he has less score. In my application I will use MT0's answer because I can recognize and remember better what is doing. I hope both will be happy with this compromise :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using a single table scan like this:

```
SELECT   "GROUP",
         100 * SUM( CASE id WHEN 'ID1' THEN value END )
             / AVG( CASE id WHEN 'ID2' THEN value END )
           AS Percentage
FROM     MyTable
GROUP BY "GROUP"
HAVING   COUNT( CASE id WHEN 'ID1' THEN 1 END ) > 0;
```

**Output**

```
GROUP PERCENTAGE
----- ----------
    1        200
    2 16.6666667
```

If you only want groups where there is exactly one row where the `ID` is `ID1` then change the last line to:

```
HAVING   COUNT( CASE id WHEN 'ID1' THEN 1 END ) = 1;
```

It is possible that you could have a group with an `ID1` row and the sum of the  `ID2` rows is zero (if you allow zero or negative values) - the query would then throw an `ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero` exception. If you want to prevent this from occurring then you can use:

```
SELECT   "GROUP",
         100 * SUM( CASE id WHEN 'ID1' THEN value END )
             / CASE AVG( CASE id WHEN 'ID2' THEN value END )
                    WHEN 0 THEN NULL
                    ELSE AVG( CASE id WHEN 'ID2' THEN value END )
                    END
           AS Percentage
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. Nice to have two different ways, both helped me a lot to learn more about SQL.

Comment: @snowflake The benefit of this solution is that the table is only read once (there is no self join). Other solutions where you first find the groups then join the table to its self will read the table (or index, if you are using them) twice and can be much slower.

Comment: Ok, I see this is an advantage. Thank you for explaining me, also your solution is easier to understand for beginners.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I need to replace with a number in case value is 0, so it was very helpful.